# Umbraco installation step 2 - "Could not save the web.config file" - IIS Permission?

Tags: asp.net, iis, permissions, iis-6, umbraco

I've managed (after much difficulty) to get to the second step of the installation of Umbraco CMS onto my local machine. I'm getting this error when I try to move onto the next step:

> "Could not save the web.config file. Please modify the connection string manually. Access to the path 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Umbraco\umbraco1\web.config' is denied."

I've tried setting Read and Write permissions on the web.config file, the umbraco1 folder AND the Umbraco folder, but nothing, same error. Restarted IIS, rebooted, still no change. I've manually changed the web.config app key which it's trying to update, but there's no way to proceed on to the next step.

There's obviously some random permission thing that I'm not doing properly, but I can't find it. On a slight tangent, when I try to open the Permissions wizard, nothing happens - any reason for this?

I'm running IIS 6, if that helps anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like permissions. Depending on how you've configured ASP.NET either the worker process identity or the IIS site anonymous user identity doesn't have write permissions.

If your master `machine.config` (in `%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG` or local `web.config` has the following line:

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

This means requests will run under the identity of the site anonymous user.

Open IIS Manager and open the properties for the `Default Website`:
[image]

Note the username in the red highlighted box, make sure this account has modify permissions on `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Umbraco` and its child folders and files.

If your `machine.config` or `web.config` specifies:

```
<identity impersonate="true" username="someuser" password="somepassword />
```

Then you need to ensure that `someuser` has write permissions on `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Umbraco` and its child folders and files.

If you don't see these configuration entries then your site will be executing under the identity of the worker process account. It's most likely this will be `NETWORK SERVICE` but you can check by opening the properties for the site in IIS Manager and selecting the `Home Directory` tab. Near the bottom you'll see `Application Pool`:
[image]

Make a note of this then navigate to the `Application Pools` node of the IIS Manager LHS pane. Right click and open the properties of the application pool noted above:
[image]

Note the identity and give that account write permissions to the Umbraco folder and its child folders and files.

Comment: Hi Kev, 

Thanks so much for the  for the in-depth response and I think setting write permissions on the Network Service is exactly what I need to do. One massive problem though - whenever I right click and select "permissions", nothing happens. I'm expecting a dialog box to appear, and I can't see any other way to set the permissions in the properties dialog (unless I'm mistaken?). Am I missing a dll in order to open the permissions wizard?

Thanks again, your advice has been invaluable so far!

Comment: @gem - where are you doing this, in IIS manager or on the physical folder in explorer?

Comment: Hi Kev - in IIS manager. I guessed that all of this was done in the IIS manager...?

Comment: @gem - not, it's better to set permissions directly on the folder in explorer.

Comment: Hi Kev - ok, brilliant, that seems to have worked! You are a legend, thank you!! :)

Comment: @gem - excellent, glad I could help out. You know you can upvote as well as marking an answer correct :)